# Migrating away from Firebase to own server & Backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We are currently using Firebase as our backend for building a chat app & we are growing significantly.
We used Firebase because it reduced our time to market due to the real time sync & offline support.

But In the near future we plan to migrate to our own server with node & mongo cause the **pricing** of the realtime database is too **high** + we have to work under a lot of **constraints** when using firebase.

**Can someone suggest how do we migrate our data directly from firebase to own server & what are some things one needs to keep in mind in such a scenario.**

Comment: We know that Firebase is a Backend as a Service which can be access via REST end point. You should migrate data from firebase to NoSQL(like MongoDB, CouchDB) and then implement your own RESTful API

Comment: Adding to what @ArifKhan said, given your desire for a chat-like interface, you will probably want to use a websocket channel interface (such as socket.io, sockjs/shoe or similar).  You may want to look at RethinkDB as it has streaming support in the box, also, Redis has channels support. depends on your needs really.

Comment: @Tracker1 Could you provide some resources/links to get started with the things u have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

**Use MongoDB + Socket.IO**
This combination gives you a lot of space for customization as you can customize the part in which user needs two-way data binding functionality.
You can connect user with socket.io in that part of application only.

To take an overview:
http://thejackalofjavascript.com/re-architecting-a-firebase-app-in-node/

Comment: Is the link still working? I get this error: "This site can’t be reached" :/